# Which Terry Pratchett character said something like "It doesn't matter if you are right or wrong, so long as you are certain"?

Tags: character-identification, terry-pratchett, the-carpet-people, bromeliad-trilogy

Which Terry Pratchett character said something like "It doesn't matter if you are right or wrong, so long as you are certain"?

I'm almost certain this isn't a *Discworld* character; in fact, I think it's in *The Carpet People* or the *Bromeliad* trilogy. But I can't find the quote itself online, and I don't have access to the books right now. The gist of the quote is that it's better as a leader to show your commitment to a decision than agonise over picking the perfect choice.

Comment: "At least you are certain when you've heard a scream" ?

Comment: No wonder I didn't recognize it. I read everything from him, except that.

Comment: @BЈовић I recommend it!

Comment: It seems to be a familiar trope; I wonder if some famous general was the original source. There is a bit in Ringworld where Louis Wu smiles at Speaker making an arbitrary choice which rimwall is closer, thinking much the same thing.

Comment: This quotation reminds me of The Forbidden Planet, when Dr. Morbius says a commander doesn't need a high IQ just a good loud voice.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Pratchett offers a range of opinions on the subject of leadership. You're likely recalling this quote from [*Truckers*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23346759-truckers), the first part of the [Nome Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/34495)

> *'The important thing about being a leader is not being right or wrong,
> but being certain. Otherwise people wouldn’t know what to think. Of
> course, it helps to be right as well,'* the Abbot conceded. He leaned
> back.
>
> <sub><sup>[Truckers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23346759-truckers)</sup></sub>

There's also the Mustrum Ridcully school of thought from *[Reaper Man](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34517.Reaper_Man?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=LOxZqfLhlg&rank=1)*

> Intellectually, Ridcully maintained his position for two reasons. One
> was that he never, ever, changed his mind about anything. The other
> was that it took him several minutes to understand any new idea put to
> him, and this is a very valuable trait in a leader, because anything
> anyone is still trying to explain to you after two minutes is probably
> important and anything they give up after a mere minute or so is
> almost certainly something they shouldn’t have been bothering you with
> in the first place.

Comment: The first quote is exactly it. The second doesn't seem close at all though?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I was merely musing on the principles of leadership.

Comment: I also like Ridcully's stand on notes/memos/essays: Everythings that is written down and not immediately shouted out is not important.

Comment: Not quite about leadership per se, but your second quote reminded me of another one of my favourite Terry Pratchett quotes: “The trouble with having an open mind is that people will insist on coming along and trying to put things in it.”

Answer (score 23):

Captain Quirke in *Men at Arms*:

> Many people are in jobs that are a little beyond them, but there are ways of reacting to the situation. Sometimes they're flustered and nice, sometimes they're Quirke. Quirke handled them with the maxim: It doesn't matter if you're right or wrong, so long as you're definite.

Comment: good find. I'd have thought it was something Lord Vetinari would have said.

Comment: Oh, but Vetinari is _always_ right!